# How to get content of html by using REST service in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

Does REST service of SharePoint 2013 support us to get the content of HTML files of specified page? What I mean is request the HTML text of display form without navigate to there, like you clicked on list item and go to page 'view item'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following request demonstrates how to retrieve page content using SharePoint REST:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Pages')/items(<item id>)?$select=PublishingPageContent
```

where

- `Pages` - the title of Pages library
- `item id` - List Item Id

**JavaScript example**

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve Publishing Page content:

```
var getPageContent =  function (webUrl,itemId,result) {
    var listTitle = "Pages";
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/items(" + itemId + ")/PublishingPageContent";
    $.getJSON(url,function( data ) {
        result(data.value); 
    });
}
```

Usage

```
getPageContent('https://contoso.sharepoint.com/',1,function(pageContent){
   console.log(pageContent); 
});
```

Comment: Hi Vadim,

It didn't work, its always return null, my code here
var abc = function(){
    var query = "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Company')/getItemById(1)?$select=PublishingPageContent";
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + query,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function(data){
            var d = data;
            alert(d);
        },
        error:  function(data){
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
}

Comment: I assumed that you are trying to get content from Pages library, could you please update your question and specify where (what field) content is stored

Comment: See the updated answer for JavaScript example

Comment: Thanks you very much, because it's already work perfectly, but except in my list because the list has a custom autocomplete lookup field, it's doesn't work with that column

Answer (score 0):

Using late [Pnp-core-js](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core) library you can do this like so:

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("News").items.getById(item.Id).fieldValuesAsHTML
 .select("PublishingRollupImage").get().then((response: any) => { console.dir(response); });
```

A example using es6 / Typescript - iterating a list of news - might look as follows:

```
public static getNewsFeed(options?: any): Promise<INewsFeedItem[]> {

return new Promise<INewsFeedItem[]>((resolve: any) => {
  pnp.setup({
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    },
  });

  pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Pages").items.get().then((response: any) => {

    let items: INewsFeedItem[] = [];
    let promises: Promise<any>[] = [];

    response.forEach(function (item: INewsFeedItem) {

      let promise = pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Pages").items.getById(item.Id).fieldValuesAsHTML.select("PublishingRollupImage").get();
      promises.push(promise);

      promise.then((response: any) => {
        items.push({ Title: item.Title, Id: item.Id, PublishingRollupImage: response.PublishingRollupImage, PublishingPageContent: item.PublishingPageContent });
      });
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
      resolve(items);
    });
  });
});
```

}

To clarify: The procedure still requires extra requests to the server.