# Get current user's wiki rankings

Tags: jquery, wiki

I am using SharePoint 2013, cloud version.  We are very limited in what we can customize.  I have created a site that uses the Enterprise Wiki template.

A feature that was requested is to show a list of favorite wiki pages.  Since it seems that a person can only "Follow" a site, I would have to get the information from the Page Rating displayed.

Is there a way, using jQuery/JavaScript to get the list of ratings for all the pages in the wiki Pages area?

I figure, if I can get all the ratings for the user, I can filter it by those with 3 or more stars and list those pages.

Comment: maybe this can help you: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117893/how-to-get-content-of-html-by-using-rest-service-in-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 2):

The following examples demonstrate how to retrieve rating information (in Ent. Wiki site wiki pages are stored in `Pages` library)

### How to get rating info via SharePoint JSOM API

```
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl; //Enterprise Wiki web site url
 getListItems(webUrl, 'Pages',
   function(items)
   {
       var ratingsInfo = {};
       for(var i = 0;i < items.get_count();i++) {
           var item = items.get_item(i);
           ratingsInfo[item.get_item('FileRef')] = { 'AverageRating' : item.get_item("AverageRating"), 'RatingCount' : item.get_item("RatingCount") };
       }
       console.log(ratingsInfo)
   },
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```

where

```
function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle,success,error)
{
   var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
   var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
   ctx.load(items);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
       success(items);
   },error);
}
```

### How to get rating info via SharePoint REST API

```
var getRatingsInfo =  function (webUrl) {
    var listTitle = "Pages";
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/items?$expand=File";
    return $.getJSON(url,function( data ) {
        var info = {};
        data.value.forEach(function(item){ 
            info[item.File.ServerRelativeUrl] = { 'AverageRating' : item.AverageRating, 'RatingCount' : item.RatingCount }; 
        });
        return info; 
    });
}

var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
 getRatingsInfo(webUrl)
   .done(function(info){
      console.log(info);    
   })
   .fail(function(error){
       console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
   });
```

Comment: Does this get the average rating for the Page?  Is there a way to get The Current User's rating for the Page?

Comment: Yes, it returns the AverageRating and RatingCount properties for pages

Comment: What about the Rating that the **Current User** gave the Page?  I apologize that I didn't clarify that part in my initial question.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to be more specific, what page, some specific page or all pages in the library?

Comment: All Pages in the Wiki Library.  I want to show all the Pages with the Current User's Rating and then filter it to Ratings 3 stars or greater.