# Sharepoint 2010 Rest api can not get RichTextField content

Tags: 2010, rest, pages, custom-content-type

I am using the Sharepoint 2010 rest api to get data of a custom content type item in "Pages" folder. The data is returned but I can not find the content of a custom RichTextField column. Is there any special setting or how should I do to get this content value ? Thanks

====Update the return data ====

Here is the returned data from the browser:
[image]

I want to get the **Page Content** field:

[image]

Comment: Is your description column is in "_Hidden" field group?

Comment: Hi Sekhar, it is not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend to double check the internal name of your field, just in case.

do you access the data retrieved like this ?

```
function onSuccess(data, request) 
{
    var itemInfo = data.d;
    // if your rich text field internal name is "Description"
    alert(itemInfo.Description);
}
```

if your field is not here, can you try to modify the rest URL by adding

```
?$select=Title,MyCustomFieldInternalName
```

at the end. See if you can retrieve Title and your field.

**EDIT**
It doesn't seem possible to retrieve the PublishingPageContent via REST in SharePoint 2010. 
It is in SharePoint 2013 :
[How to get content of html by using REST service in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117893/how-to-get-content-of-html-by-using-rest-service-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Thank Sylvain, I checked the return data but dont see this content.

Comment: ok, thanks for the details. I added something which is worth trying.

Comment: Hi, The browser returns this error "Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.PagesItem' does not have a property named 'PublishingPageContent"' when I select this field. Also, if I select the Title only, it is success.

Comment: I am sorry I think it is not possible in SharePoint 2010, Akhoy's solution is a way you can explore.

Comment: Thanks for your supporting. I will try Akhoy's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Getting PublishingPageContent using REST doesn't seem to be possible especially in SP 2010 where you have limited options. You can use JSOM to do this:

```
function retrieveListItems() {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteurl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Pages');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
//camlQuery.set_viewXml('');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));  
}
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

var listItemInfo = '';

var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() +             
        '\PageContent: ' + oListItem.get_item('PublishingPageContent');
}
console.log(listItemInfo); // returns ID and PageContent
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Thank Akhoy, I need call the SP webservice from an iphone application. Does the JSOM work with my app. Also, I am trying with the SOAP api but it requires the web id to retrieve.

Comment: In that case, I don't think this would work. You'd have to create a custom web service and call that from the iPhone app. This will only work from within SharePoint so maybe you could have a custom list where you are outputting this and then querying that. But it wont work from within the app.

Comment: Thanks, I am referring this post https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms464040(v=office.14).aspx to create a custom webservice for my app.

Comment: hi Akhoy, I am testing the new custom webservice. I call it from jquery but the request is 401 - Unauthorized error. I tried the soap /_vti_bin/authentication.asmx?op=Login but it's not luck. How can I authenticate for my html file ?

Comment: The user wouldn't have permissions. Check if this helps : http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/08/03/a-tip-to-remember-when-calling-custom-web-services-in-sharepoint-from-javascript-or-jquery.aspx

Comment: Hi Akhoy, I call the default SP webservice (Login), it still 401 error. I think I dont parse the user to authenticate with Sharepoint. In console app, I can by add the Credential by `request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");`. 
My question is how can I authenticate for my call first ? Thanks.

Comment: If the user doesn't have permissions to call the web services, then you need to give him permissions first. You can't impersonate credentials like in console app.

Comment: I used the Administrator account to call the web service. It is still 401 error.

Comment: Then this might be a problem with how you've hosted it in IIS. The 401 error is usually from IIS authentication problems.

Comment: Start googling from there.